# the angular component html doesn't recognize the mat-libraries

Tags: angular, typescript, import, toolbar, declaration

I had been looking why does this component I made is getting this errors. I mean it says it doesn't recognize the angular mat libraries but I already imported every mat module I use and even I declared the component on there, so I really don't understand why do I get that error.

[Error of the component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDTCz.png)

[Module imports and declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvI8o.png)

Comment: Can you post your code on Stackblitz?

Comment: Where is educativo.module.ts being imported?

Comment: Need [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try importing the corresponding modules inside app.module.ts and again ng serve.